# angular 4 route to same component does not trigger change detection via async pipe

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I'm trying to route to the same component with a different param that changes Observable that is subscribed in the template by async pipe. Pretty much as per the book: https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action with an exception that I change Observable when the paramMap emits new value but somehow the change does not get detected or detection does not happen.

Angular v.4.3.6

Template:

`<div *ngIf="game$ | async as game" class="card">`

Component:

```
game$: Observable<AdminGame>;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    ....) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.game$ = this.route.paramMap
        .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
            let id = params.get('id') || '';
            if (id === 'newGame') {
                return Observable.of({} as AdminGame);
            }
            return this.adminService.getGame(id);
        });
}
```

Initially I visit component as "/adminGame/newGame" which binds `Observable.of({} as AdminGame)` then in it I get the new id and navigate to "/adminGame/id-of-new-game":

```
this.router.navigate(['/adminGame',id]);
```

which should bind to results of `this.adminService.getGame(id)`.

Although I can see the data from the service comes through, the async did not detect any change.

There is no problem if I route somewhere else and then go to `['/adminGame',id]`

On other similar topics there are references to *out of ngZone* but I reckon my service is just a generic http Injectable service in Angular.

**edit:**

It even works if I do the same assignment just before the navigation change:

```
this.game$ = this.adminService.getGame(id);
this.router.navigate(['/adminGame',id]);
```

Why does async not detect the change in switchMap?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: just as I mentioned in the edition - I had to manually reassign the changed observable before running router.navigate